# ¿Django se usa para trabajar en el backend?

Tags: python, django, aplicación-movil

me interese la programación de app movil(apps para celulares), y quero aprender backend para tener app's mas complejas. y e leído que python es un lenguaje muy popular para el backend, así que me anime a aprenderlo, por lo que he leído, se usa el framework Django y he visto que la mayoría lo usa para diseño web, pero si quero trabajar solo en el backend para mis app's debo usar Django u otro framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Llevo usando Django para el backend desde hace años, y sí, es frecuente su uso y muy recomendable por diversos motivos:

- *Lenguaje Python*: hace más fácil y dinámico el desarrollo, a la vez que potente. Si bien es más lento, su impacto no es relevante en backend dado que la mayoría del procesamiento se va a hacer con bibliotecas optimizadas o directamente compiladas en C y utilizadas desde Python. Si se buscase algo más de velocidad para cálculos especiales quizá podrías echar un vistazo al lenguaje Go (o Golang) pensado para hacer backends con rendimientos cercanos a C++, pero yo perferiría python + cython.
- *ORM: Object Relational Mapper* es la sintaxis propia de Django para hacer consultas (queries) y escritura a bases de datos (normalmente SQL: sqlite, mysql, mariadb, postgre, pero también hay drivers para No SQL como cassandra, MongoDB...). Permite comunicarse con cualquier base de datos utilizando una sintaxis mucho más sencilla y menos propensa a errores que las consultas SQL. **Este aspecto de Django es, en mi opinión, la clave de su éxito**, permite una interacción muy buena y consistente con las bases de datos.
- *Django Rest Framework*: Para crear APIs backend con Django, se suele utilizar [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/): permite automatizar muchos aspectos de la generacion de vistas API mediante las que obtener información de los modelos Django desde el frontend, haciendo muy robusto y "DRY" (Don't Repeat Yourself) la construcción de APIs.

Para hacer una API no necesitas más que eso. Aunque Django tiene su propio sistema de plantillas (Templates) para hacer frontends renderizados en servidor, muchas veces es utilizado sólo para backend.

Answer (score 0):

Si, Django es un framework de backend basado en python, aquí puedes tener más inromación sobre este framework: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.1/